# refactoring a file and a folder into a new git repository

Tags: git, github

I followed the potential solution in

[Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475)

My requirement is similar but only slightly different Hope someone could provide some easy solution.

Say I have the following repo:

```
node-browser-compat
├── ArrayBuffer
├── Audio
├── Blob
├── FormData
├── atob
├    ├──aaa.xyz 
├── btoa
├── location
└── navigator
```

I want to have a new repo `abcd` which has all of `btoa` and `aaa.xyz` in it while retaining the history of both `btoa` and `aaa.xyz`.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Note: If I already have an empty repo called `abcd`, instructions to moving `btoa` and `aaa.xyz` into `abcd` will also help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Dan Lowe, looks exactly how I wanted it. I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got a longish history or a largeish worktree, this will be dramatically faster if you avoid unneeded churn.

Make a scratch ref-surgery repo on the fastest filesystem you can find, that's a tmpfs (on windows you'll want to install a "RAM disk", [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/) has worked well for me).

```
scratch=`mktemp -dt`
git init --template='' $scratch
cd !$
echo /path/to/your/node-browser-compat/.git/objects >.git/objects/info/alternates
```

Make a nonce checkout, then set up all your branch refs:

```
git checkout $(git commit-tree $(git mktree <&-) <&-)
git fetch /path/to/your/node-browser-compat/ --no-tags +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

Now you can rewrite anything you want with a completely free hand -- if anything goes wrong, just abandon and rm -rf.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '
        git read-tree --empty
        git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT atob/aaa.xyz btoa
' -- --all -- atob/aaa.xyz btoa
```

and you can clone or push any part of the result to wherever you want.

On a four year old midrange chip (3570K) this took about five minutes to do all ten years of git's history, rewriting 11924 commits, about a quarter of the total, that happened to alter the `t`ests directory or `builtin/var.c`.

(edit: replaced  `origin` with actual pathname, the remote name was a holdover from an earlier version)

Comment: `code`
Rewrite ... (1/189) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    /usr/lib/git-core/git-filter-branch: line 372: read-tree: command not found
Usage: reset [options] [terminal]
Options:
-c set control characters
-e ch  erase character
-I       no initialization strings
-i ch  interrupt character
-k ch kill character
-m     mapping  map identifier to type
-Q     do not output control key settings
-r      display term on stderr
-s      output TERM set command
-V     print curses-version
-w     set window-size
index filter failed: 
>         git read-tree --empty
`code`

Comment: Thanks for your response 
Got above result at the git filter-branch... command

Comment: Looks like a typo when you tried it, there's no way on earth it can't find `git read-tree`, and it's complaining about not being able to find `read-tree`, so I'm thinking transcription error of some sort.

Comment: You were right. I had copied up an extra > from a previous command. I retried by copying command from your suggestion directly and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we have more than one solution, but I propose this solution:
Since you didn't mention about branch, I suppose that you have only one branch.

Create a new empty Git repository named `abcd`, https://example.com/USERNAME/abcd.git

Clone `node-browser-compat` to `abcd`

```
git clone URL_of_node-browser-compat
git remote set-url origin https://example.com/USERNAME/abcd.git
git push -u origin master
```

Prune unnecessary folders/files:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf ArrayBuffer' --prune-empty HEAD
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf Audio' --prune-empty HEAD
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf Blob' --prune-empty HEAD
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf FormData' --prune-empty HEAD
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf location' --prune-empty HEAD
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf navigator' --prune-empty HEAD
```

If directory/folder `atob` has more than 1 item `aaa.xyz`, let prune other folder/file in same way.
Then push to repository `abcd`

```
git add -A .
git push
```

Reference

https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch